# In Excel, OnClick I need to save then add a workbook to a SPT 2010 Standard Edition doc Library? How to do this?

Tags: 2010, excel

I am not a coder, but I have seen VB scripts that "kind of" does this.. I'm willing to try (nervous smile).

I need to add a button in an Excel workbook that will "auto upload" the workbook to a SharePoint Document Folder located here: 
"http://mycompany.com/sites/hit/XXXX/RiskAssessmentAttachments/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

The Excel file has macros enabled.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't File -> Save and Send, Save to Sharepoint work well enough?